# What's the difference between classification/clustering and zoning?

Tags: classification, clustering, land-cover, land-use, terminology

A week ago I had an exam and there was a question:

> What are the main steps of zoning in a GIS?

I didn't understand the question and asked the instructor what does she mean by zoning (in Persian `پهنه‌بندی`) and she gave me this explanation:

> -- For example you have an image or a vector of a region and want to determine which parts are used for agriculture, which parts are sterile, etc.
>
> -- I'm afraid do you mean the same as classification?
>
> -- I can't give you more instructions

I didn't understand and I gave the following answer (main steps of classification)

1. Extracting features (more than one) for each pixel or each information unit
2. Optimizing the features to choose the best ones that can provide better separability between classes
3. Optimizing the classifier parameters (eg. in SVM we need to optimize `C` and `Gamma` based on the data that's going to be classified
4. Training the classifier if we're taking a classification approach (this step is not needed for clustering)
5. Classifying pixels based on optimized features through optimized classifier

But seems that this answer is wrong. Then:

- What's the difference between `classification/clustering` and `zoning`?
- What are the main steps of `zoning` in a GIS?